# Permissions in SharePoint 2010

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-enterprise

we did migration of eRoom to sharepoint using docave migration tool. After the migration i checked the permissions. folowwing groups with permissions.

owner -  full control, limited access

member - Contribute, Limited access

visitor - Read, Limited Access

Will having limit access affect the default behaviour? if yes how can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Limited access just means that that group or person has been given explicit access somewhere on the site. No need to worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

Permissions are additive, meaning that, for example, 'member' has *both* contribute access as well as "limited access".  What "limited access" means is that the user/group is able to tell that the entity exists.  It's basically a pre-requisite for having any permission level to that entity, or any child entities.

To give a simple example, perhaps you have a group that you want to have access to a list on the site, but not to be able to do *anything* on any other part of the site.  You can give them contribute access to the list (after breaking inheritance) but they'll still need 'limited access' at the site level of just hitting the root site will give them an access denied.